# AngularJS ng-repeat with seperator every two items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The layout I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Doing this gets me the divs, but how can I add separators between every two items? I feel like Angular should have an easy way to do this.

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="object in objects"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: shouldn't the `row` object repeat?

Comment: Sure, but I don't have a ```row``` concept in the model, so I have nothing to repeat against

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think, you can solve it using a bit of javascript and ng-repeat like

```
<div>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="array in obj2">
        <div ng-repeat="object in array">{{object}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then in your angular controller create a new object called obj2 using the objects array like

```
$scope.obj2 = [];
while ($scope.objects.length) {
    $scope.obj2.push($scope.objects.splice(0, 2))
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kUa9N/)

Comment: Is there a way to automatically update the second obj2 array when the first changes?

Comment: You could add a watch on the first array and call a function to build the second when it changes.

Comment: FYI, don't forget the "p". Used .slice on accident and formed an infinite loop. Just drove me crazy, hopefully saves someone a headache.

Answer (score 3):

If i get what you want to do, you could use the `$index` property of [rgRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and then use [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) for that index like:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects">
    <div>My Content</div>
    <div data-ng-show="$index % 3 == 0">My Seperator</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is the separator doesn't go inside the object, it divides every two objects. It's a layout problem, not a visual one.