# Insert new row every x elements in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a markup like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-50" ng-repeat="picture in pictures.slice().reverse()">
        <a href="instagram://media?id={{picture.id}}" title="{{picture.caption.text}}" target="_blank">
            <img ng-src="{{picture.images.standard_resolution.url}}" width="100%" height="auto" alt="{{picture.caption.text}}" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create an even layout, with two images every row. The issue is, I need to add a new row every two, so my `ng-repeat` isn't working. For example, the markup should look something like this once it's rendered:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-50">
        <a href="instagram://media?id=213" title="Blah blah" target="_blank">
            <img ng-src="something" width="100%" height="auto" alt="Blah blah" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-50">
        <a href="instagram://media?id=213" title="Blah blah" target="_blank">
            <img ng-src="something" width="100%" height="auto" alt="Blah blah" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-50">
        <a href="instagram://media?id=213" title="Blah blah" target="_blank">
            <img ng-src="something" width="100%" height="auto" alt="Blah blah" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-50">
        <a href="instagram://media?id=213" title="Blah blah" target="_blank">
            <img ng-src="something" width="100%" height="auto" alt="Blah blah" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Short of doing the output manually with Javascript, I'm not really sure how to do it. I've been looking at the docs, but I can't find a way to do it. Could someone suggest something, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS ng-repeat with seperator every two items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391656/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-seperator-every-two-items)

Comment: My first response was probably not compatible with all version of angular, please have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

Using ng-switch should work as long as your pictures array is even in length.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="picture in pictures.slice().reverse()" ng-switch on="$index % 2"  ng-show="$index%2==1">
  <div class="col col-50" ng-switch-when="1">
      <a href="instagram://media?id={{pictures[$index-1].id}}" title="{{pictures[$index-1].caption.text}}" target="_blank">
        <img ng-src="{{pictures[$index-1].images.standard_resolution.url}}" width="100%" height="auto" alt="{{pictures[$index-1].caption.text}}" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-50" ng-switch-when="1">
      <a href="instagram://media?id={{picture.id}}" title="{{picture.caption.text}}" target="_blank">
        <img ng-src="{{picture.images.standard_resolution.url}}" width="100%" height="auto" alt="{{picture.caption.text}}" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Simple example of how this works in Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/5711/